# How to apply placeholder to Google Visualization control wrapper string filter input?

Tags: google-visualization

I have to apply placeholder to Google Visualization control wrapper string filter input.I tried with

```
var stringFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'StringFilter',
      'containerId': 'search_container',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'Name',
        'matchType':'any',
        'ui': {'label': ''}
       }
});

google.visualization.events.addListener(stringFilter, 'ready', function(){
   $(".google-visualization-controls-stringfilter").prop('placeholder', "Search..");
});
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the `<input>` that is inside the div with the class `.google-visualization-controls-stringfilter`:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(stringFilter, 'ready', function () {
    $('.google-visualization-controls-stringfilter input').prop('placeholder', 'Search...');
});
```