# Add placeholder to multiple google chart string filters

Tags: javascript, filter, google-visualization, placeholder

I referenced this post [How to apply placeholder to Google Visualization control wrapper string filter input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384260/how-to-apply-placeholder-to-google-visualization-control-wrapper-string-filter-i)
to figure out how to add a placeholder to google chart filter.

```
//FILTER1

    var building_filter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'StringFilter',
        'containerId': 'building_filter-div',
        'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Bldg Name',
            'ui': { 'labelStacking': 'horizontal', 'label': 'Building:' }
        }
    });
         google.visualization.events.addListener(building_filter, 'ready', function () {
         $('.google-visualization-controls-stringfilter input').prop('placeholder', 'Building Name');
    });

//FILTER2

    var maintenance_type_filter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'StringFilter',
        'containerId': 'maintenance_type_filter-div',
        'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Maint Type',
            'ui': { 'labelStacking': 'horizontal', 'label': 'Maintenance Type:' }
        }
    });
        google.visualization.events.addListener(maintenance_type_filter, 'ready', function () {
        $('.google-visualization-controls-stringfilter input').prop('placeholder', 'Maintenance');
    });
```

It works, as long as you don't have more than one filter you want to add placeholder to.

In this code, it's applying the same 'Maintenance' placeholder to both inputs, ignoring the top placeholder.

How can I add placeholders to each input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use the `id` of the `<div>` element, instead of google's class name...

```
$('#building_filter-div input').prop('placeholder', 'Building Name');

$('#maintenance_type_filter-div input').prop('placeholder', 'Maintenance');
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Where did you find this in the documentation/how do you know this? I feel like learning this API is like trudging through molasses when it should be easier for me.

Comment: this is basic jquery, we start with the id of an element we know exists, then find the type of element we want inside the first element.

Comment: True, why do we wrap google.visualization.events.addListener around this?

Comment: we need to wait until the control has been drawn, otherwise, the input will not exist when the selector is run...